# Self join in LINQ query and return View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using LINQ Self Join Query to display data on the view .my sql table contains some employees details .I need to show employee details with their Manager Name 
as it is ManagerID in the table as

```
EmpID  Name ManagerID   Designation Phone   Address
1   Mike    3          Developer    123456  Texas
2   David   3           RM          123456  Delhi
3   Roger   NULL        GM          123456  Dallas
4   Marry   2          Developer    123456  NY
5   Joseph  2          Developer    123456  Singapore
7   Ben 2              Developer    123456  Mumbai
8   Steven  3          TL           123456  Banglore
```

i need to change it to name

my code is in controller action

```
var emp = from m in t.Employees
          join e1 in t.Employees on m.ManagerID equals e1.EmployeeID
          select new { Id = m.EmployeeID , 
                       Name = m.Name, 
                       Manager = e1.Name , 
                       Designation = m.Designation,
                       Phone =m.Phone ,address = m.Address };

return View(emp.Tolist());
```

and in View

```
@model IEnumerable <mvc4application.models.employee>
```

but I am getting runtime error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.Int32,System.String,
>   System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Mvc4application.Models.Employee]'.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +405487

Off Course i am understanding this because my view is using `Mvc4application.Models.Employee type` .

As I am not able to cast it to model type .

can we use SQL view as model in MVC, so that we can do joining in SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are returning an anonymous object whereas your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<mvc4application.models.employee>`.

I would very strongly recommend you writing a view model that will match the requirements of your view and contain the information you would like to be working with in this view:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

and then adapt your LINQ query in order to project the various domain EF object into the view model:

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> employees = 
    from m in t.Employees
    join e1 in t.Employees on m.ManagerID equals e1.EmployeeID
    select new EmployeeViewModel
    { 
        EmployeeID = m.EmployeeID , 
        Name = m.Name, 
        ManagerName = e1.Name,
        Designation = m.Designation,
        Phone = m.Phone,
        Address = m.Address 
    };

    return View(employees.ToList());
```

and finally make your view strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model IList<EmployeeViewModel>
```

and now you could present the information:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Manager name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].EmployeeID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ManagerName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Designation)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Phone)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Address)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but why a `for` loop and not a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Because I just hate it. There are gazillion of blog posts illustrating how to use `foreach` loops in Razor views and gazillion of questions on StackOverflow about why model binding doesn't work for collections. It's just that when you use the strongly typed editor helpers with a foreach loop they won't generate proper names for the input fields. In this case it doesn't matter because there aren't any input fields, but I just don't want to teach people using those foreach because I just sense that the next question will be why can't I submit the data back to my controller action.

Comment: So I used `for` instead of `foreach` in an anticipation of possible next questions from the OP :-) As soon as he replaces the Html.DisplayFor with Html.EditorFor and places the `<table>` into an HTML form and attempts to submit this form he will get nasty surprise if he used foreach.

Comment: All right, I never had any problems with it, but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Darin Thanks .
definitely this is Nice answer but be a novice to ASP MVC i have this question that only for one Property (ManagerName) we have to create a model.can we use anonymous object to display data in view.

Comment: No, you can't use an anonymous object. Anonymous objects are not intended to ever be leaving the method in which they are defined. In this case you are passing an anonymous object to the view and in this view you can't do anything with it.