# asp.net-MVC Self join in LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm using `LINQ Self Join Query` to display data on the view. My `SQL` table contains some employees details. I need to show `Employee-Manager` inside the `DropDownListFor` control. I've tried this query and it works, however not the way I want. The query displays the `Employee-Manager` as in `{ EmployeeManagerID = Roger  }`, but it should display only `Roger`. What is wrong with the query below?

```
var empmngr = from m in db.Employes
                  join e1 in db.Employes on m.EmployeeManagerID equals e1.EmpID
                  select new
                  {                          
                      EmployeeManagerID = e1.Name, 

                  };

        ViewData["EmployeeManager"] = new SelectList(empmngr.ToList(), "Name");
```

The view:

```
  <div class="editor-label">
        EmployeeManager
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name,   ViewData["EmployeeManager"] as SelectList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

     </div>
```

The employee table:

```
 EmpID  Name EmployeeManagerID  Designation  Phone   Address
   1   Mike    3                 Developer    123456   Texas
   2   David   3                 RM          123456   Delhi
   3   Roger   NULL              GM          123456   Dallas
   4   Marry   2                 Developer    123456  NY
```

Comment: Where is Ali in your table?

Comment: @The_Outsider sorry `Roger`  not ali

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self join in LINQ query and return View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610890/self-join-in-linq-query-and-return-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing and a list of anonymous type to the `SelectList`, so it doesn't know how to show it.

You should select only the `Name` property and have a list of strings:

```
var empmngr = from m in db.Employes
              join e1 in db.Employes on m.EmployeeManagerID equals e1.EmpID
              select e1.Name;
```

btw, the second parameter on the `SelectList` is the `selectedValue`, `"Name"` doesn't seem appropriate here.

Comment: now i have problem i don't have EmployeeManagerID  in the back of the name of the EmployeeManagerID   i face problem when i try to insert new record the EmployeeManagerID     =null any advice